# AWS Codestar - DynamoDB Not Authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have a codestar project that calls a python lambda function. This function tries to put an item into the DynamoDB. I am getting the following error:

`"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PutItem operation: User: arn:aws:sts::13556632xxxx:assumed-role/CodeStar-split-lambda-Execution/awscodestar-split-lambda-lambda-CreateUser-RBA73BJH7NHY is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:1355663xxxx:table/split-users"
}`

I included the `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`, `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`, and `AWSLambdaInvocation-DynamoDB` policies on the `CodeStar-split-lambda-Execution` role, and I am still getting the error.

I also made my own policy and tried it too.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:13556632xxxx:table/split-users"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get dynamoDB to have authorization to put an item?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, it was a problem with the permissions boundry. I cant quite remember excatly what though. Sorry!